# Как заменить событие hover на событие загрузка страницы

Tags: hover, загрузка, css, javascript

Кто знает, как сделать? Есть определённое событие hover в стилях css, при наведение на картинку она вертится и тухнет, и на её месте появляется другая. Как сделать, чтобы всё то же самое выполнялось, только не при наведении, а при загрузке страницы автоматом?

Вот код:

```
.layer3 {
background: url(../images/logo1.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
-moz-transition: 2.0s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: 2.0s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 2.0s ease-in-out;
transition: 2.0s ;
}

.layer3:hover{
background:url(../images/r.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Для Firefox */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Для IE */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Для Opera */
transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transition: 2.0s ease-in-out;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы всё это было не при наведении, а при загрузке страницы?

Перефразирую вопрос: как сделать, чтобы данное действие выполнялось не при наведении мыши, а при загрузке страницы?

Comment: тег не "java", а "javascript"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот так?](http://jsfiddle.net/910hbg5v/)

Comment: Огромное спасибо) я догадывался, что это должно быть просто, но за не знанием javascript не мог сделать. Ещё раз спасибо, буду пытаться подучить javascript.